# Improve performance of operation on numpy trigonometric functions

Tags: python, performance, numpy, trigonometry

I have a rather large code which I need to optimize. After some analysis using `time.time()`, I've found that the line that takes up the most processing time (it is executed thousands of times) is this one:

```
A = np.cos(a) * np.cos(b) - np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) * np.sin(c - d)
```

where all the variables can be randomly defined with:

```
N = 5000
a = np.random.uniform(0., 10., N)
b = np.random.uniform(0., 50., N)
c = np.random.uniform(0., 30., N)
d = np.random.uniform(0., 25., N)
```

Is there a way to improve the performance of the calculation of `A`? As I'm already using `numpy`, I'm pretty much out of ideas.

Comment: *"all the variables can be randomly defined with..."*  Is that the actual use-case that you are interested in, or did you use `np.random.uniform` just to have some data for the stackoverflow question?

Comment: Is this happening in a loop? Can it be put into a matrix format and vectorised?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser the latter. The actual data comes from the missing piece of my rather large code.

Comment: @JamieBull in a way it is happening in a loop, but I'd need to reformat my entire code to simply wrap a `for` around that line.

Comment: Does `numpy` include a `sincos` function that computes sine and cosine of the same argument simultaneously? If so, using that will likely cut down the time spent in computing trig functions considerably.

Comment: @njuffa apparently it does not: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2626

Comment: Too bad, most modern computing environments offer that function. You may want to consider adding your input to the existing `numpy` feature request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using the [product-to-sum trig. identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities), you can reduce the number of trig. function calls.  In the following, `func1` and `func2` compute the same value, but `func2` makes fewer calls to trig. functions.

```
import numpy as np

def func1(a, b, c, d):
    A = np.cos(a) * np.cos(b) - np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) * np.sin(c - d)
    return A

def func2(a, b, c, d):
    s = np.sin(c - d)
    A = 0.5*((1 - s)*np.cos(a - b) + (1 + s)*np.cos(a + b))
    return A
```

Here's a timing comparison with `N = 5000`:

```
In [48]: %timeit func1(a, b, c, d)
1000 loops, best of 3: 374 µs per loop

In [49]: %timeit func2(a, b, c, d)
1000 loops, best of 3: 241 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you tried to use so Python accelerator like Numba, Cython, Pythran or anything else?

I did some test with Pythran. Here is the result:

Original code :

- Python + numpy : 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.43 msec per loop
- Pythran : 1000 loops, best of 3:777usec per loop
- Pythran + SIMD : 1000 loops, best of 3:488 usec per loop

Code provided by Warren:

- Python + numpy : 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.05 msec per loop
- Pythran : 1000 loops, best of 3: 646 usec per loop
- Pythran + SIMD : 1000 loops, best of 3: 425 usec per loop

This is done with N = 5000

- Update * :

Here is the code :

```
# pythran export func1(float[], float[], float[], float[])
# pythran export func2(float[], float[], float[], float[])
import numpy as np

def func1(a, b, c, d):
    A = np.cos(a) * np.cos(b) - np.sin(a) * np.sin(b) * np.sin(c - d)
    return A

def func2(a, b, c, d):
    s = np.sin(c - d)
    A = 0.5*((1 - s)*np.cos(a - b) + (1 + s)*np.cos(a + b))
    return A
```

And command line:

```
$ pythran test.py  # Default compilation
$ pythran test.py -march=native -DUSE_BOOST_SIMD  # Pythran with code vectorization
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Pythran` and I don't know what `SIMD` stands for. Could you give some more details?

Comment: SIMD means : Single Instruction Multiple Data. It is a concept use in modern architecture to process multiple values at the same time (here, multiple cells of these arrays). Modern cpu handle avx (or avx2) which may process 4 cells in a row.
About Pythran, it is a python to c++ compiler which optimize given code. It handle only constraints Python code (statically typed code and some others restrictions) but it works (and focus) on scientific kernel (like this one).

Comment: Something simple like `numexpr` will get you about the same speedup as Pythran + SIMD.